# Net Core 2.0 API setting up authorization and authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .net core application that I have upgraded from 1.1 to 2.0.
The problem I am having is working out how to set up both authentication and authorization.

I am getting this exception when I am trying to hit an api endpoint...

> 2017-08-15 15:28:12.2191|13|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|ERROR|
>   Connection id "0HL73T7CAJGBE", Request id "0HL73T7CAJGBE:00000001": An
>   unhandled exception was thrown by the application. No
>   authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no
>   DefaultChallengeScheme found.

My controller has this attribute on it...

> [Authorize(Policy = "Viewer3AuthPolicy")]

My startup.cs has this method to try and set everything up...

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    SetCorsPolicy(services);

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });

    SetAuthorisationPolicy(services);

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        options.AddPolicy("Viewer3AuthPolicy",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.AuthPolicyClaimsName, Constants.AuthPolicyClaimsValue));
    });
}
```

In my Configuremethod I am calling...

> app.UseAuthentication();

I am thinking that I must have some ordering wrong or am making the wrong calls in the setup.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Authentication in asp.net core 2.0 has changed, i hope you find the answer

Comment: I think this is you need : https://wildermuth.com/2017/08/19/Two-AuthorizationSchemes-in-ASP-NET-Core-2     core 2.0 has big difference with core 2.0 preview.     here is implantation with angular as front end: https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETcoreAngularJWT

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `_userManager.AddClaimsAsync`. Here is the simplified version of changes I made under **ConfigureServices**:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {       
    options.AddPolicy("CRM", policy => { policy.RequireClaim("department", "Sales", "Customer Service", "Marketing", "Advertising", "MIS"); });
});
```

AccountController constructor:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private readonly MyDB_Context _context;

    public AccountController(
        MyDB_Context context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Under **LogIn**:
(*var vUser* is my own class with properties *Name, department, SingIn, etc*...). The sample below uses combination of custom user table ***mytable*** (to read from claim types and their values) and ***AspNetUserClaims*** table (to add claims):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var vUser = _context.mytable.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Email.ToUpper() == model.Email.ToUpper());

        const string Issuer = "https://www.mycompany.com/";
        var user = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();

        ApplicationUser applicationUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
        IList<Claim> allClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(applicationUser); // get all the user claims

        // Add claim if missing
        if (allClaims.Where(c => c.Type == "department" && c.Value == vUser.department).ToList().Count == 0) {
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("department", vUser.department, ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
        }
        // Remove all other claim values for "department" type
        var dept = allClaims.Where(c => c.Type == "department" && c.Value != vUser.department);
        foreach(var claim in dept) {
            await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, new Claim("department", claim.Value, ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
        }

        vUser.SignIn = DateTime.Now; _context.Update(vUser); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(vUser.Name, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded) {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor) {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut) {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

This is what I have in my **controller**:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CRM")]
public class CRMController : Controller
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it shortly and let you know what happens.

Comment: Is _userManager your own class or a .net type?

Comment: it's .net type, generated by choosing Authentication "Individual User Accounts". I've updated  the answer with my Controller constructor.

Comment: I'm using combination of AspNetUsers table (generated by application) and my custom table with all the claims in MyDB_Context.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
AddJwtBearer(options => { options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; ... });"
```

did the trick for me.

[dotnet core 2.0]