# ASP.NET Core 2.0 HttpSys Windows Authentication fails with Authorize attribute (InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I am trying to migrate an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application to ASP.NET Core 2.0.

The application is fairly simple and involves the following:

- Hosted on HttpSys (formerly WebListener)
- Using Windows authentication: `options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM`
- Allowing anonymous authentication: `options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true` (because there are some controllers that do not require authentication)
- Controllers that require authentication are decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

The project compiles and starts up just fine.  It also serves actions of controllers that do not require authentication.

However, as soon as I hit a controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified,
and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.<ChallengeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I started fiddling around with the project templates and noticed that I could reproduce this easily using the standard template *ASP.NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller)* with Windows Authentication.

The Program.cs file was changed as follows:

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                options.MaxConnections = 100;
                options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000");
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

This comes straight from the [HttpSys documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys).  Also I added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the `HomeController` class.  Now, it will produce exactly the same exception as shown.

I found some related Stack Overflow posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695136/net-core-2-0-api-setting-up-authorization-and-authentication), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805411/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-middleware) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961571/asp-net-core-2-0-preview-1-how-to-set-up-cookie-authentication-with-custom-logi)), but none of them deals with plain Windows Authentication (and the answers do not seem to generalize).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

While writing up the post, I remembered coming across [this subsection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#windows-authentication-httpsys--iisintegration) of the migration guide.  It says to add

```
services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

to the `ConfigureServices` function.

I initially thought that this wouldn't apply to HttpSys, given the full name of the constant (especially the `IISIntegration` threw me off).  Moreover, as of this writing, the [HttpSys documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys) completely fails to mention this.

For those targeting the full .NET Framework, this requires installing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` NuGet Package.

**EDIT**

As Tratcher points out, there is a similar constant from the `HttpSys` namespace you should rather use:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60#issuecomment-327484192

Comment: You can replace IISIntegration.IISDefaults with HttpSys.HttpSysDefaults, they happen to have the same value.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer.

Comment: This solution worked for me along with @Tratcher's recommendation. My situation was a little different from the OP's. I had a brand new Core 2.2 app that began life without authentication. The "no authenticationScheme" error appeared after Windows Authentication was activated and [Authorize] was added to a controller action.

Answer (score 9):

Andreas' answer got me on the right path but this is what worked for me:

Added package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication`

and then for *Startup.cs*

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another thing,  if you've already added `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`
make sure to turn on an authentication type (windows, forms) in IIS under the app → authentication.

Mine were all disabled and was getting this error even with the code in place.

Comment: Thank you! These settings seem to "reset" themselves back to Anonymous for some reason. A link to this answer now accompanies a note in my source code.

Answer (score 3):

If it's still not working, make sure you configured launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    //...
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    //...
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
   //...
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    //...
    }
  }
  //...more stuff
}
```