# How do you use both anonymous and windows authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Having trouble enabling both Anonymous and Windows authentication working when using http.sys as webserver in ASP.NET core 2.0. It works fine when I host in IIS but refuses to work in http.sys server. Method tags `[Authorize]` on HomeController `Windows` action fails with HTTP 500 and never prompts for authentication.

Program.cs

```
   .UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.Schemes =  AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | 
   AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
        options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000");
    })
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Windows()
        {
            return Content ("You are " + User.Identity.Name +  "; Authentication Type:" + User.Identity.AuthenticationType );
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Anonymous()
        {
            return Content ("You are " + User.Identity.Name +  "; Authentication Type:" + User.Identity.AuthenticationType );;
        }
    }
```

Exception

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ChallengeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
```

Comment: When you receive a 500 error you should always post the exact exception message, how else should people help you?

Comment: Exception added.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add following to "services" section despite the fact that it's not hosted in IIS

```
services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Per
[ASP.NET Core 2.0 HttpSys Windows Authentication fails with Authorize attribute (InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818095/asp-net-core-2-0-httpsys-windows-authentication-fails-with-authorize-attribute)